# javascript regex find words containing only one dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I have program:

```
var str = "ac.def=1 and xy.z.kt='10' and k.t=1 or xy.z.kt.lm='10'";
var regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9,]*[.]{1}[^=]');
var result = str.split(" ").filter((elem, index) => {
    return regex.test(elem);
})

console.log(result);
```

I get result as: `["ac.def=1", "xy.z.kt='10'", "k.t=1", "xy.z.kt.lm='10'"]`

but I need to get only : `["abc.def=1", "k.t=1"]`

---

it is said that my question is possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) so lets close stackoverflow forever, because all questions about software programming has an answer in their own official documents.

Please be careful when marking a question as a possible duplicate of an official documents. Otherwise we should close all questions about regex since [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) is enough to solve all problems about regex. Right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Do you want to select `ac.def=1.5`  or `def=1.5` too?

Comment: @Potato No, because there are 2 dots

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Looking at the regex provided by him, it seems that he wants a single dot only to the left side of assignment `=` irrespective of what how many dots are at the right side of `=`. Not sure though...

Comment: @Potato Fair enough, I assumed the *word* is a streak of non-whitespace chars here (judging by the `split(" ")` method), so a single dot is allowed anywhere inside. Then, if the single dot should come before `=`, this requirement must be reflected in the title - it is a very important bit.

Comment: Then, `/^[^.=]*\.[^.=]*=/` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `/^[^.]*\.[^.]*$/` regex:

```js
var str = "ac.def=1 and xy.z.kt='10' and k.t=1 or xy.z.kt.lm='10'";
var regex = /^[^.]*\.[^.]*$/;
var result = str.split(" ").filter((elem, index) => {
    return regex.test(elem);
})

console.log(result);
```

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^.]*` - 0+ chars other than `.`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^.]*` - 0+ chars
- `$` - end of string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/z0Wyyi/1).

**Alternative, single-regex, solution**

You may collect your matches using a single regex like

```
/(?:^|\s)([^.\s]*\.[^.\s]*)(?!\S)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mk8TPQ/1/).

**Details**

- `(?:^|\s)` - a non-capturing group matching start of string or whitespace
- `([^.\s]*\.[^.\s]*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[^.\s]*` - 0+ chars other than a `.` and whitespace
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[^.\s]*` - 0+ chars other than a `.` and whitespace
- `(?!\S)` - no non-whitespace allowed immediately to the right of the current location (a whitespace or end of string can appear to the right)

JS demo:

```js
var s = "ac.def=1 and xy.z.kt='10' and k.t=1 or xy.z.kt.lm='10'";
var results = [];
s.replace(/(?:^|\s)([^.\s]*\.[^.\s]*)(?!\S)/g, ($0, $1) => results.push($1));
console.log(results);
```

**If there must be a single dot before `=`**, use

```
/^[^.=]*\.[^.=]*=/
```

within your code. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z0Wyyi/2). The difference is that the regex no longer has `$` at the end, `=` is at the end as it is enough to stop checking there, and `=` chars are added to the negated character classes to prevent them from matching across these symbols.

Comment: @Cid Just added the explanation and the [demo link](https://regex101.com/r/z0Wyyi/1).

Comment: What if the word contains only a `.`?

Comment: @Potato Then, it will be extracted.